# Subversion and excel xll file

Tags: svn, microsoft-excel-2003

It is a business requirement to keep xll files in subversion (trust me, I did not come up with this idea :-) ).

Now when I try to load this file up in Excel, Excel opens it like what you see in attached screen shot: [image]

The mime-type of this file is set to 'application/x-dosexec' in subversion. It is assigned by subversion. I did not change this value.

I have run checksum on the xll file and I can confirmed the file is not corrupted.

**My question:**

Can this problem has anything to do with incorrect mime-type in subversion? If so, what is the proper value?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, where you got "xll is readable by Excel file", because it isn't correct: XLL may and have to be opened by Excel, but not in order to be readed, but - to be used.

[XLL is](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fileextensions/f/xllfile.htm)

- compiled
- DLL

> Can this problem has anything to do with incorrect mime-type in subversion?

No

- Subversion mime/type settings affect **always** only Subversion operations
- It's more or less good file-type for binary DLL

Comment: I did not attempt to 'read' the file. I was just trying to load the xll file by dragging it from explorer to an Excel instance. Normally it works fine but not this time.